# How can I connect my PayPal account with my Fidelity account?

Tags: money-transfer, paypal, fidelity

How can I connect my PayPal (based in the United States) account with my Fidelity account?

I don't see Fidelity amongst the bank options when trying to add a new external bank account in my PayPal account on https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/money/banks/new:

[image]

[image]

I have also tried searching for "Fidelity Investments".

I have no issue connecting my Bank of America account.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/pNnnEK

Comment: Isn't Fidelity a brokerage firm, rather than a bank?

Comment: looks like you can do it https://www.fidelity.com/cash-management/mobile-payments. I would contact Paypal support. Looks like a bug

Comment: Just type in the ACH routing number instead of picking the bank's name from a list.  This is more reliable anyway since many banks have multiple routing numbers.

Comment: You have to click link another way:
https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/money/banks/new?type=MANUAL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cropped the screenshot.  In the portion you cropped is a link for "Don't see your bank" which allows you to identify the bank via ACH routing number.

[image]

This is more reliable anyway since many banks have multiple routing numbers